# Where is the New Oxford American Dictionary stored?

Tags: macos, unix, dictionary

I'm trying to build a command line tool to look up definitions of words, it's only a dummy app for me to practise my C++ skills.

I know there is a list of words stored at `/usr/share/dict` - but what I'm really looking for is the path to the New Oxford American Dictionary data, it comes bundled with the system, but I couldn't find it yet.

Comment: Apple provides API for C to access the dictionary services. Do keep in mind, that programming is off topic here - you might be better off seeing about looking for help on development topics at Stack Overflow. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/access/access.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006152-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dictionaries are stored in...

```
/Library/Dictionaries
~/Library/Dictionaries
```

[image]

Comment: Is this still accurate as of 10.14? /Library/Dictionaries and ~/Library/Dictionaries are empty.

Answer (score 7):

In 10.14 (and possibly earlier), the dictionaries have moved to
`/System/Library/Assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX/`

There is one `.asset` directory for each downloaded dictionary; for example, my American English dictionary is located at: `/System/Library/Assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX/69b7ab1cf0f75ad16bf6662b0a77fbfd36b7941f.asset/AssetData/New\ Oxford\ American\ Dictionary.dictionary`.

**UPDATE**
In macOS 11.5, it seems to be a slightly different path:
`/System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX`